# What is a better English idiom that can be used to express a love of learning?

Tags: metaphors, idiom-request

I am looking for a better expression or idiom that can serve as an analogy to 'I love learning' in this sentence:

The literal translation would be: **I love learning. I absorb new information as a sponge absorbs water.**

And ... I have never heard nor read such analogy in english so while it sounds understandable, I'm afraid it looks like something that screams I'm not a native english speaker because a native speaker would say something completely different and more typical. But I may be wrong.

Is there a better sounding analogy in english or possibly an idiom?

Comment: Actually, your use of the sponge is quite common. However, I would recommend you look up two words: metaphor and simile.

Comment: Pretty much the same question was asked on ELU years ago (long before ELL existed), and [one of the answers there](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/51903/2637) specifically suggested ***mind like a sponge***. I think the idea of asking for an "equivalent" here is too subjective/open-ended.

Comment: I wouldn't use any such phrase in a job interview or resume (if that's what you're thinking). It's an overused metaphor and as such, it would be cliche, especially in reference to yourself.

Comment: @Fumble - If we rephrase the question just a little bit (_"Is there an English idiom that expresses a love of learning?"_), then this is a perfectly suitable ELL question – at least in my mind. I wish you had left your comment as an answer, and not voted to close.

Comment: J.R.: ok I changed the title

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but two useful and related words are "bibliophile" and "autodidact".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a *mind like a sponge* is a common use idiom in English but it has a slight connotation that someone is **capable** of absorbing large amounts of information. This wouldn't be out of place in your use but, if you want a phrase that more generally means someone who loves to learn, you could say something like:

> I'm hungry for knowledge.

Or, a more natural way of writing what you said in your translation would be:

> I love learning and absorb new information like a sponge.

This implies that you love to learn and you do with ease.

The "absorbs water" at the end is actually implied, so it's unnecessary, particularly as sponges absorb lots of different things, not just water.

Answer (score 3):

You could consider 'scholar', although this also implies teaching (but, arguably, teaching implies a love of learning: choose your poison.)

> "a person who is highly educated or has an aptitude for study." - [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=scholar&oq=scholar&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1671j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=scholar+meaning)
>
> "I'm a scholar at heart"

Another such word is 'philomath', as mentioned on [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163232/what-term-means-one-who-enjoys-learning).

> "A philomath ... is a lover of learning." - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philomath)
>
> "My teacher is a philomath"

Answer (score 2):

It's more common and natural if you say I am very fond of learning. It also sounds good if you say I am thirsty for knowledge.  More simply, you can say I like learning very much.